# Cannot get rid of Warning: React state update on unmounted component during tests RTL

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I'm writing integration tests.  This file renders the `<App />`, fills an input, and submits a search before each test.  The tests all pass.  However, I cannot get rid of:

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
```

I don't get this warning in the app, only tests.  I've read dozens of posts but none of the solutions (`act()`, `wait()`, `waitFor()`, etc...) make any difference.

Here is the test code, I've left the bare minimum of what causes the warning (where I grab `goBackBtnText` after clicking the `submitBtn`:

```
describe('Results Page', () => {
  let goBackBtn, nearbyBtn;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    ZIP_API_MOCK();
    FDIC_API_MOCK();
    render(<App />);

    const zipInput = await screen.findByPlaceholderText(searchFormText.placeholder);
    const submitBtn = screen.getByText(searchFormText.submitBtn).closest('button');
    input(zipInput, VALID_ZIP_WITH_RESULTS);
    userEvent.click(submitBtn);
    const goBackBtnText = await screen.findByText((content) =>
      content.includes(resultsText.goBackBtn)
    );
    goBackBtn = goBackBtnText.closest('button');
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    userEvent.click(goBackBtn);
  });

  it('true', () => {
    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

The line where the warning is thrown:

```
 44 |     }
      45 |     if (newResults.fiList.length > 0) fwdToPath = PATHS.RESULTS;
    > 46 |     setResults(newResults);
         |     ^
      47 |     setLoading(false);
      48 |   };
```

And this is what really confuses me.  Because `goBackBtn` is on the results page and the test successfully sees it. So `setResults` has already been run and a side effect has been executed which is to redirect to the results page.

I'm aware I'm misunderstanding something, just not sure what anymore.  Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `'mounted'` variable, to tell whether it should skip the call to setState or not (**cleanup function**).

Check the example below for a Grocery List taken from internet:

```
 import "./App.css";
    import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
    import { getList, setItem } from "././services/list";
    
    function App() {
      const [alert, setAlert] = useState(false);
      const [list, setList] = useState([]);
      const [itemInput, setItemInput] = useState("");
      const mounted = useRef(true);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        mounted.current = true;
        if (list.length && !alert) {
          return;
        }
        getList().then((items) => {
          if (mounted.current) {
            setList(items);
          }
        });
        return () => (mounted.current = false);
      }, [alert, list]);
    
      const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setItem(itemInput)
          //When the setItem promise resolves, clear the input and set the alert message
          .then(() => {
            if (mounted.current) {
              setItemInput("");
              setAlert(true);
            }
          });
      };
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (alert) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            if (mounted.current) {
              setAlert(false);
            }
          }, 1000);
        }
      }, [alert]);
    
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>My List</h1>
          <ul>
            {list.map((item) => (
              <li key={item.item}>{item.item}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
          {alert && <h2> Submit Successful</h2>}
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <label>
              <p>New Item</p>
              <input
                type="text" 
                onChange={(event) => setItemInput(event.target.value)}
                value={itemInput}
              />
            </label>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks, Ani.  This is a good answer and I have implemented something similar to make the warning go away.  I guess I'm also trying to figure how to do this without polluting the app code (perform the check or abort in tests only).)

Comment: Glad to help! I usually perform the check where I need to set States, inside UseEffect() hooks, in each component of my app. It might seem too much, but till now I have not found another way of getting rid of the warning above.

Comment: I made it a custom hook so I just call `const isMounted = useIsMounted()` at the very top of the component, and then check when I want to early return with `if (!isMounted.current) return;` That way I don't add a lot of unnecessary clutter to the components.