# Getting can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component on Material Ui Progress Indicator

Tags: reactjs

Getting a material ui specific error. Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component  on Material Ui Progress Indicator

```
index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    in ProgressIndicator (at Loader.js:25)
    in div (at Loader.js:24)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Grid))
    in ForwardRef(Grid) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)) (at Loader.js:23)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Grid))
    in ForwardRef(Grid) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)) (at Loader.js:22)
    in Loader (at MyPage.js:217)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a cleanup function when you set states in your app.
Check out my answer here:
[Cannot get rid of Warning: React state update on unmounted component during tests RTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67811117/cannot-get-rid-of-warning-react-state-update-on-unmounted-component-during-test/67819502#67819502)

This will solve your issue.